# How to open browser on a button click event of a Phonegap Apps

Tags: javascript, android, html, iphone

We have a PhoneGap apps using HTML and JavaScript.We want to access PayPal website on a button click event of the Apps and after payment revert back to Apps.How we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is one inapp browser event in phonegeap you can use that like below,

```
  Ref = window.open(url,'_blank','location=no');
  Ref.addEventListener('loadstart', LoadStart);
  Ref.addEventListener('loadstop', LoadStop);
  Ref.addEventListener('exit', Close);
```

Use function like this you will get callback event. On that remove event.

```
Close = function(event){
       console.log("app "+event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
       iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
       iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
       iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
}
```